# find with multiple greps

Tags: c, text, grep, find

I need to find lines of code after malloc that does not contain the word null,
so that I can understand if the malloc was properly checked or not.

For example the following lines should be printed:

```
obj = (boolean *) malloc(DAYS_IN_WEEK * sizeof(boolean));
    for(int i = 0; i < DAYS_IN_WEEK; i++){
```

This command partially works since it prints out the lines containing malloc

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' \( -exec grep -HnA2 'malloc' {}  \;
```

should I add another grep? Not sure how to do it.

Comment: Site note: Don't forget that some programmers prefer to write `if (!obj)` in the next line.

Comment: agree with previous comment.  Additionally consider _all the other ways/places_ that the pointer can be verified.  As long as it is verified before use, it can be on the same line as `malloc()`, the next line, or the line after that,...   the forms `NULL` or `null` may be used, or not.   lexically  ensuring `malloc()` was properly checked will be non-trivial.

Comment: @ryyker thanks. do you know if there is any static analyzer that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something easier but this seems close:

```
find . -name "*.c" -exec grep -nHA1 malloc {} \; | 
   awk '/^--/ {next} /malloc/{f=1; p=$0; next} f==1 && !/NULL/{f=0; print p; print $0}'
```

Explanation:

- `/^---/ {next}` ignores all lines starting with dashes that `grep` generates
- `/malloc/{f=1;p=$0;next}` sets a flag `f` if the line contains `malloc` then remembers the line in `p` and moves to the next
- `f=1...` checks if the flag is set (i.e. the previous line contained `malloc`) and the current line doesn't contain `NULL`, and if so, prints the previous and current lines